# Html5 App in AppHub

Tags: html, windows-phone, marketplace

I just want to know if it is possible to sell appplication in marketplace written in HTML5 ? Are there any drawbacks ? I know we can develop app using Silverlight or XNA, but what about HTML 5 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, yes !
The are many frameworks like PhoneGap that can help us.
Basically, it use WebBrowser Control and navigate to internal pages.